# android eclipse alertdialog double box

Tags: android

I have created an alertdialog box for my android app but I seem to be getting 2 boxes in the alert box.

Below is my code for the alert box;

```
AlertDialog.Builder AlertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
AlertBox.setTitle("Alert");
AlertBox.setMessage("Username or password is incorrect.");
AlertBox.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
AlertBox.show();
```

Am I doing something stupidly obvious to cause this? How can I get rid of the box behind the alertdialog.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: builder -> create() then show

Comment: @sherpya @Setu [AlertDialog.Builder.show](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java#L950) calls `AlertDialog.Builder.create`.

Comment: Can you paste the full class. There is not enough info to solve this. I suspect that you are calling this method twice or there is another alert dialog behind this. The only way to tell is to see the full logic flow

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
AlertDialog.Builder AlertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder AlertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
```

Set the style in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

[If you take a look at the theme applied when you use](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java#L134):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

You'll see that it points to `com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_Alert`

Which looks like:

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowTitleStyle">@android:style/DialogWindowTitle.Holo.Light</item>
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>
```

When you look at the theme you're applying `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth`, you'll find:

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>
```

They key difference being the `android:windowBackground` attribute.

If you create your own style with `Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth` as the parent and apply the `android:windowBackground` attribute, you'll find that the "double box" is no longer visible, but transparent:

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

For the sake of highlighting this, here's what you get when you set the `android:windowBackground` attribute to `@android:color/holo_red_light`:

[image: Example]